# How to control Godot RigidBody using mouse velocity?

Tags: mouseevent, game-physics, godot

I represent player's character as a RigidBody which is controlled with mouse input. I tried to catch unhandled input and apply its event velocity like that

```
func _unhandled_input(event: InputEvent) -> void:
    if event is InputEventMouseMotion:
        apply_central_force(event.velocity)
```

However the mouse eventually escapes game's window or hits its borders and futher inputs do not occur. I tried to lock the cursor in place by manually warping it to the center of the screen with `get_viewport().warp_mouse(get_window().size / 2)`, but warping also triggers input event which accelerates my character to opposite direction.

Then I tried to disable input handling before warping and enable it after with

```
set_process_unhandled_input(false)
get_viewport().warp_mouse(get_window().size / 2)
set_process_unhandled_input(true)
```

but it does not change anything.

I also tried to get cursor stuck in place by setting `Input.mouse_mode = Input.MOUSE_MODE_CAPTURED`. It hides the cursor and locks it to the center of the screen but it also does not allow it to accelerate, so its velocity is always a zero vector.

There is `relative` property available instead of velocity. `relative` is `The mouse position relative to the previous position (position at the last frame)`. Unlike `velocity`, it is not affected by `mouse_mode`, but for some reason its values are snapped to integers which result in janky movement.

What I want to achieve is movement similar to that from a game called Hammerfight (2009).

Comment: Are you sure you want a force, not an impulse?

Comment: @Theraot honestly, I am not. However, the problems remain the same